# How can I affect a transcluded element without a transclude function?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to transclude an element from the DOM into a directive and then affect that transcluded element by changing its style or adding event listeners to it.  If I use a transclude function, I can do those things to the clone element.  However, if I choose to use a transclude function, the `<ng-transclude>` directive becomes redundant.  I want to be able to alter the transcluded element but not have to manually place the clone.

I'm coming from a Dojo background where I would use `data-dojo-attach-points` to be able to get hooks into where I want pieces to go or attach listeners.  I figured AngularJS would have some sort of answer to how to deal with this.

```
app.directive("hex-nest", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: (
            "<div>" +
                "<span>Hello</span>" +
                "<span>[WHERE_I_WANT_TO_TRANSCLUDE]</span>" +
                "<span>World</span>" +
            "</div>"
        ),
        badTemplate: (
            "<div>" +
                "<span>Hello</span>" +
                "<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>" +
                "<span>World</span>" +
            "</div>"
        ),
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFunc) {
            transcludeFunc(scope, function (clone) {
                clone.on("click", function () {
                    console.log("I was clicked");
                });
                // This will append to the end of the element, 
                // not in the middle of the children
                element.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I have already tried writing nested directives that pass a transcluded element down to where it should go, but that doesn't seem to work.

The code above is just an example.  The end result that I am shooting for is to have a directive that will wrap some kind of form element, an `<input>` or `<select>`, and produce a text node representing that node's value.  Whenever you click on that text node, a small modal will appear with the original form element in it, similar to how the **Small edit dialog** is designed in Google's [Material Design Data tables interaction document](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction).

I have been able to accomplish this using standard JavaScript as well as an additional implementation using JQuery where I manually add multiple elements and bind up listeners; but I want to lean Angular and this is coming as sort of a road block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the element tag to a name you can find:

```
    template: (
        "<div>" +
            "<span>Hello</span>" +
            "<my-transclude>[WHERE_I_WANT_TO_TRANSCLUDE]</my-transclude>" +
            "<span>World</span>" +
        "</div>"
    ),
```

Then find it and append to it.

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFunc) {
        var myElem = element.find("my-transclude");
        transcludeFunc(scope, function (clone) {
            clone.on("click", function () {
                console.log("I was clicked");
            });
            //  
            // 
            myElem.append(clone);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Oh man, I get it now.  I misunderstood the [element documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).  I don't know what I was thinking, but I guess I just read "Limited to lookups by tag name" and only considered `<div>` or `<span>` etc which wouldn't help if I had more than one as a child. I didn't even think about custom named tags like that which would make sense with how you use directives anyway.  I'll try that whenever I can.

Comment: Yes, a browser puts elements and attributes in the DOM even if it doesn't know how to render them. The AngularJS framework finds those elements and attributes and injects directives with scopes, controllers, templates, etc.